# Modeling proportions of autocorrelated binary data

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, binary-data, proportion

I have data on infant crying for three time periods -- 1994-1996, 2000-2002, and 2010-2013 -- with about 15 infants per year. Each infant was observed every minute for 1080 minutes (across 3 days). If the infant was crying, a 1 was recorded, otherwise a 0. The data I have is the proportion of these 1080 observations in which crying was observed. In this plot, each dot is one infant:

[image]

The question I want to answer is: has the proportion of time infants cry changed in this population across these three time periods. Normally, I would model this in R like so:

```
m = glm(p_crying ~ year, family=binomial, weights=w, data=d)
```

where p_crying is the proportion of time crying, year is the year, and w is a vector with the number of observations for each infant (1080).

However, it is almost certain that the observations are autocorrelated, whereas the above model assumes that the 1080 observations are independent. For 1994-1996 only, I have the raw binary observation data (not just the proportions), and the autocorrelation function indeed indicates autocorrelation. Here is the ACF plot for one infant:

[image]

If I had the raw data for all three time periods, I could probably figure out some way to model this with a glmm (e.g., including some lag variables as fixed effects), but I only have the raw data (all 1080 binary observations) for the 1994-1996 time period. Can I somehow use the autocorrelation data from 1994-1996 to adjust the weights for the later time periods? Or?

My question is: how can I model the change in crying over time using the data that I have?